# Regular expression except first

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have string that could be like this:

```
%a%%%%%bc%%%d%
```

I need to replace the first % and the last %, at the start and at the end of the string with "".
Also i need to replace all the %+ except the first one for each sequence group of string.

Result should be like this:

```
a%bc%d
```

How can I do with regex ? I tried something like this:`.*?%(\W+)%` but it didn't work

Thanks.

Comment: more info please. is your string complete or will it occure in a longer sting with stuff before and/or after?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
.replaceAll("^%|%$|(%)+", "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/epG4D1/1)

**Details**:

- `^%` - the `%` at the start of the string is matched
- `|` - or
- `%$` - a `%` at the string end
- `|` - or
- `(%)+` - a repeated capturing group that matches 1+ `%` symbols, but captures only one `%` at each iteration into Group 1, and later, the `$1` backreference to this group replaces multiple `%` chars with 1 `%`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by Wiktor is nice. However if you need to know whether or not the input actually matches the pattern, you may wish to try a solution like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("%([^%]+%)%*([^%]*%)%*([^%]+)%");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if(m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + m.group(2) + m.group(3));
} else {
    System.err.println("The pattern didn't match");
}
```